# Secure access from app to mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, fluent-nhibernate, security, remote-access

I have a problem with new hosting. So far I have been using an fluent nhibernate aproch to access data from remote database. Due to certain circumstances I had to change to another hosting which don't have external database access. End users use internet connections without static IP (it is public for most of them, but it changes every 24-48h) What can I do in my situation to keep changes at minimum in my application ?

Data transfer is in both ways.

My ideas:

- Use new hosting ftp to upload files for processing with php. Lots of work.
- Design some kind of webaccess service. Same as above.

Out off above questions comes second one:
How access to database is provided in big systems where one can't limit connection only to known and safe sources ?

DMZ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have external access to a database (which is pretty common if not the default) you could use a VPN or SSH tunnel to connect to the external server and access the database as if it were a local one.

Comment: Is it possible with application only ? Is there some req. for server ?

Comment: Yes, you need a SSH client on the server and you may want to execute CLI commands from your application.

Comment: Looks like lots of work... I wonder if it would be better to port C# to php ?

Comment: @Gwynnbleid1 It doesn't matter, which programming language you use. The problem is, that you had accessed to database on a remote server without using a secure connection. You probably haven't mentioned that as an error until yet – but now it bites you. In fact, you won't need to re-implement you app. Just set up a SSH tunnel for the remote database under a second port (e.g. 3307) and use this database as it were a local one.

Comment: I have found another hosting company with public access to database for now. I also decided to implement api for my app. Still vpn would solve my problem without much work on app side.